# Does Gemfury's proxy support "npm update" and "npm outdated"?

Tags: gem-fury

I'm not seeing update-to-date responses from Gemfury about package versions the way I'd assume I would. I've got my ~/.npmrc file configured with:

```
registry=https://npm-proxy.fury.io/MyaPiTokEn/myaccountname/
```

and I'm logged in with `npm login`. I know some things work because I can do things like:

```
npm install my-private-package
```

and my-private-package exists only on Gemfury. When I run `npm outdated`, however, I do not get any response about a package I have put into Gemfury even though the package's version shows in the Gemfury UI as 1.0.4, the version in my app's "node_modules" directory is 1.0.3, and my app's "package.json" file has a dependency with "^1.0.2".

In fact, in order to update my app after I update the Gemfury repo via a `git push`, I have to actually delete the package directory from my app's "node_modules" directory and then run `npm update`.

If I do that, I'll pull the very latest 1.X.X version as my package.json specifies. If I don't delete the package directory first, no update will happen. Is there something misconfigured that comes to mind, or does npm-proxy.fury.io not support the queries my npm CLI is sending?

Comment: You might be running into [npm/npm#17911](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17911)